# When does static NSString* const mystring=@"SomeString" ; gets loaded into memory

Tags: objective-c, macos, header-files, static-variables, load-time

I have moved all string literals getting used in my app to a header file :
myheader.h---

```
static NSString* const mystring1=@"SomeString1" ; 
static NSString* const mystring2=@"SomeString2" ; 
static NSString* const mystring3=@"SomeString3" ; 
static NSString* const mystring4=@"SomeString4" ; 
static NSString* const mystring5=@"SomeString5" ;
```

and in main.cpp:

```
#include myheader.h

main(){
...code using  NSString* from header;
}
```

Will that increase my app load time?

Comment: Is like asking if the fan is on will I open the door faster. The compiler will perform a lot of string optimisation, what you are trying to do by hand - you should really not worry about this kind of stuff. Do you have poor app load time that you want to fix? Then I think the trouble is elsewhere.

Comment: "Will that increase my app load time" - did you measure it?

Comment: Yes I am trying to solve poor app load time of an app that integrates my library. Binary size has not been changed and execution time of my API is also same if i compare that with the previous version.